# how to deny access to a directory in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to deny access to my pdfs directory so others cannot access the pdf files in that dir by trying something like `www.example.com/pdfdir/test.pdf`

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Administrator"
AuthUserFile /home3/nimabida/public_html/power-plant/src/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

its ok for denying other request but now the problem is i cant show these files in my website and it require user/password there too! how can i show them without login?

Comment: Though this is possible you should ask yourself if that really is a good solution. In general it is a better idea not to store objects not meant to be published by the http server _outside_ the folder explicitly meant to be published. So to store your PDF documents _outside_ your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder for that http host. You can still publish those files using a request router inside your application logic. Which allows you to do whatever authorization check you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably block access to a directory if you want to be able to link directly to these files on your site and have them available to your users.

The "best" you can do is to check the `Referer` HTTP request header to make sure the user is following a link on your site and not typing the URL directly (ie. no `Referer`) or following a link from a 3rd party site. (But note that this is unreliable - see below.)

For example, in the `/pdfdir/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com/
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Where `example.com` is your site's domain. This blocks any request that does not originate from your site. (Commonly referred to as "hotlink" protection.)

However, this is unreliable. A determined user can easily fake the `Referer` header to gain access to these files and some legitimate users may not send the `Referer` header so will be blocked.

The only way to reliably block unauthorised access is to use some kind of authorisation (username/password). But in this case, the files would ideally be stored outside of the document root and served to the client by your script once the user has been authenticated.